# Fibonacci Adder Machine - Calculating Digits in Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: python, loops, fibonacci

I'm working on a program that will calculate fibonacci numbers with certain digit limitations (i.e. first fibonacci number with 100 digits). The code I have below overall is running, but I am hitting a logical error that has me stumped.

The goal of the code is to calculate Fibonacci numbers in a fashion similar to binary addition. Using an array, each element is to hold a digit from 0 - 9, so each array index represents a 10's place.

It starts working and looping through fine, but it gets off between 13 and 21 because of the way the loop is handled. It adds the number sin the 10's place together and then saves a 31 number.

Is there a way to break out or stop it from adding those together that I'm not seeing?

```
num1 = [0]*100
num2 = [0]*100
num2[len(num2)-1] = 1
carry = 0
flag = True

while (flag):
    #Main for loop to work through the array
    for count in range (1, len(num2)):
        carry = num2[len(num2) - count] + num1[len(num1) - count]
        if carry > 9:
            num2[len(num2)- (count + 1)] = num2[len(num2)- (count + 1)] + 1
            carry = carry % 10
            num1[len(num1) - count] = num2[len(num2) - count]
            num2[len(num2) - count] = carry
        else:
            num1[len(num1) - count] = num2[len(num2) - count]
            num2[len(num2) - count] = carry
    print(num2)
    if num2[0] != 0:
        flag = False
```

Each time it passes the main while loop I'm hoping to see

```
[0,0,...,0,1]
[0,0,...,0,2]
[0,0,...,0,3]
[0,0,...,0,5]
[0,0,...,0,8]
[0,0,...,1,3]
[0,0,...,2,1]
...
```

but after it hits the [...,2,1] loop it moves on to [...,3,1]

Comment: It's missing the definition of num1. Is it as num2 (all 0 except on the right)?

Comment: It's in there, must not have copied it whenever I grabbed the code to paste here. I'll edit so it's more clear.

Comment: @LukeMorris, I am not so clear what your output should be? Can you clarify that in your question please?

Comment: the error is already when num2 = 8 and num1 = 5, at the first carry: at count = 1 you modify num2 to 13, then at count = 2 you use that 1 (the carry) to sum into num1 which gets 15 and not 8 as expected. Use a debugger ;-) I guess you could remember there was a carry and subtract it at the next count, or you need to change your logic on how to update new 1 and 2

Comment: I would say, remember there is a carry to add at the next loop, but don't do it in the current digit. That should work best!

Comment: Is this just an exercise? Because python has infinite precision integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a cleaner version of what I believe you're trying to get at.

```
#Init of Fib variables 
a = 0
b = 1
num = 10  #Change this to the number of fib calculation loops.
x = 0
output_arr_len = 100 #Change this to 10 for testing, as it's easier to see.    

while x < num:
    #Calculate Fib Sequence
    c = a + b 
    a = b
    b = c 
    x += 1

    #Output Array
    print([0] * (output_arr_len - len(str(c))) + [int(i) for i in str(c)])
```

Below is the output of the first 20 loops with `output_arr_len` set to 10.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 7]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 9, 7]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 8, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 8, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 6, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Your answer works, but not for arbitrarily large values, as you're relying on the integer maximum values. The question, really working digit by digit instead of only displaying that way, was more generic...

Comment: @B.Go There is no integer maximum value in Python (subject to memory),  which makes me wonder why the OP is doing it this way at all.

Comment: @MarkTolonen OK, thanks for the info. But I still think that the answer is better using the same kind of algorithm as what was in the question, and should fix that algorithm, rather than using a different one!

Answer (score 0):

It was even more tricky than in my comments, but this version works correctly:

```
num1 = [0]*10
num2 = [0]*10
num2[len(num2)-1] = 1
sum = 0
carry = 0
flag = True

while (flag):
    #Main for loop to work through the array
    for count in range (1, len(num2)):
        sum = num2[len(num2) - count] + num1[len(num1) - count] + carry
        num1[len(num1) - count] = num2[len(num2) - count]
        if sum > 9:
            sum = sum % 10
            carry = 1
        else:
            carry = 0
        num2[len(num2) - count] = sum
    if carry == 1:
        num2[0] = num2[0] + 1
    print(num2)
    if num2[0] != 0:
        flag = False
```

You have also to copy to new1 before applying the carry, even when doing it at the next higher bit...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrections to your code. Note that Python has infinite precision integers, so I've added a Fibonacci generator to check the answer.

```
num1 = [0]*100
num2 = [0]*100
num2[len(num2)-1] = 1
flag = True

# Fibonacci generator for verification of answer
def fib():
    a,b = 0,1
    while True:
        a,b = b,a+b
        yield a

# Instance of the generator
f = fib()

# convert a list of single-digit integers to a real integer for display
def value(L):
    assert all(n < 10 for n in L) # bug checking for invalid list values.
    return int(''.join([str(i) for i in L]))

while (flag):
    #Main for loop to work through the array

    # Start with zero carry for first digit
    carry = 0

    for count in range (1,len(num2)+1): # originally off-by-1.

        # compute the sum plus the carry of previous sum
        temp = num2[len(num2) - count] + num1[len(num1) - count] + carry

        # shift num2 digit to num1 digit
        num1[len(num1) - count] = num2[len(num2) - count]

        # new num2 digit is the one's place of temp sum.
        num2[len(num2) - count] = temp % 10

        # remember the carry (10's place) for next sum.
        carry = temp // 10

    # Check for bugs...compare the answer with the next Fibonacci number
    assert value(num1) == next(f)

    if num1[0] != 0:
        flag = False

print(value(num1))
```

Note you can make the for loop a little simpler by remembering that negative offsets access an array from the end (`num2[-1]` is the last item in the array) and `range` can count backwards:

```
for count in range(-1,-len(num2)-1,-1):
    temp = num2[count] + num1[count] + carry
    num1[count] = num2[count]
    num2[count] = temp % 10
    carry = temp // 10 # remember carry for next digit
```